# Allowing other host to connect to postgresql-9.1 and restart services in postgresql-9.1

Tags: postgresql-9.1, suse-linux

We need to add few Ip address in our pg_hba.conf file so that some new servers can connect to our postgresql database. We did the changes to pg_hba.conf like below

old pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             10.150.0.0/16           password
host    all             all             10.156.14.0/23         password
```

New Ips to be added to pg_hba.conf

```
10.24.8.1 
10.150.256.170 
10.150.256.133
```

We had done the changes to pg_hba.conf and added entries like below(we directly added IP address without /16 or /32) 
New pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             10.150.0.0/16           password
host    all             all             10.156.14.0/23         password
host    all             all             10.24.8.1              password     
host    all             all             10.150.256.170         password
host    all             all             10.150.256.133         password
```

Now, we need to restart the postgresql-9.1 server. I tried the below commands but nothing worked.

```
postgres:~> service status postgresql-9.1
Absolute path to 'service' is '/sbin/service', so it might be intended to be run only by user with superuser privileges (eg. root).
-bash: service: command not found
postgres:~> service postgresql-9.1 status
Absolute path to 'service' is '/sbin/service', so it might be intended to be run only by user with superuser privileges (eg. root).
-bash: service: command not found
postgres:~> systemctl status postgresql-9.4
If 'systemctl' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found systemctl
-bash: systemctl: command not found
```

This is the server info having postgresql-9.1 installed

```
postgres:~> uname -a
Linux camboxtest1 3.0.101-108.87-default #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 16:42:57 UTC 2019 (10e85a8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Did i add the IP address in right format ? What will be the command to restart the postgresql-9.1 services?

Comment: Which Linux distribution is that?

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I will plan a upgrade soon, but upgrade also required database restart. I need to find the command to start stop postgres services. I had one another server where we had 9.4 and for that "systemctl start postgresql-9.4" is working fine.

Comment: The way you restart a service depends completely on the Linux distribution you use. So which one is it? e.g.  `cat /etc/*release*` or something similar.

Comment: Btw: you don't need to restart Postgres to apply the new settings: `select pg_reload_conf();` will apply the new values from `pg_hba.conf` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please find below info
postgres@camboxtest1:/data> cat /etc/*-release
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64"
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="11.4"
VERSION_ID="11.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:11:4"
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 4

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about _select pg_reload_conf();_. How can I find the restart command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96216/discussion-between-ksingh-and-a-horse-with-no-name).